# In AWS glue workflow, a conditional trigger is not actuated after all the watched event finished running successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

In the AWS workflow, I created a trigger that will watch for SUCCEEDED status for 4 different jobs, if they are successful then it will call a different glue job.  I have checked the status of the jobs, they have run successfully. But the trigger is not actuated after all the four dependent jobs ran successfully.

Comment: have you activated the trigger after creating?

Comment: yes, the status shows ACTIVATED.

Comment: I have the very same issue, started acting like this on Friday. How did you resolve the issue?